# Checking a column in 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays

i want to check only columns in a 8x8 array.is it require two for loop or only one for loop.

Comment: Well, how would *you* code this?

Comment: I love the smell of homework in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check one column you need one loop, if you want to check N columns you need two nested loops.